# Can't install Umbraco Headless .Net Client

Tags: .net, nuget, umbraco

I am currrently tinkering with the new Umbraco Headless and I am looking just to get some data to pull through, I have managed this with node and now I am looking to do this in an asp.net application.

I have been following the instuctions here:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Headless/Headless-Net-Client/website-framework

I am running the command:

```
Install-Package UmbracoCms.Headless.Client -Source https://www.myget.org/F/uaas/api/v3/index.json -Pre
```

And getting the error:

```
PM> Install-Package UmbracoCms.Headless.Client -Source https://www.myget.org/F/uaas/api/v3/index.json -Pre
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03' with respect to project 'Umbraco Headless 3', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03'
Resolved actions to install package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03' does not exist in project 'Umbraco Headless 3'
Package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client.0.9.0-CI-20180405-03' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Harriet\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Umbraco Headless 3\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'UmbracoCms.Headless.Client 0.9.0-CI-20180405-03'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package UmbracoCms.Headless.Client -Source https://www.myget. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? It seems like there is something wrong with the version of .net but I have the project set to 4.6.1... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the DotNet client only supports DotNet Core.  I could be wrong though

Comment: Robert is correct, the .Net client is Core only at the moment.

Comment: I tested this again at work using VS 2017 (at home I use 2015) and it worked, maybe it is something to do with the visual studio version.